# AJAX Form Submission - "Return False" & "preventDefault" not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using a form submission tool to get information from an API. The server I'm connecting to is notorious for timeouts - so I have the submission on a jQuery timer, with a "check" system to make sure I'm not already waiting on the server to respond to another request.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the triggered `.submit()` to NOT reload the page. No matter how many `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()`'s I use - either the form never submits or the page reloads.

Cheers.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {

        var check = jQuery('div#go').length;

        var count = parseInt(jQuery('h3.timer').html());

        count++;

        jQuery('h3.timer').text( count );

        if ( check ) {

            //alert( 'running' );

            jQuery( 'form#woowps_next_page' ).submit(function(event) {

                event.preventDefault()

                jQuery('div#go').remove();

                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/wp-content/plugins/wps-woo/inc/category_repair_ajax.php',
                    data: jQuery("form#woowps_next_page").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {

                        alert( 'win' );

                        var current_page = jQuery('input.woowps_next_page').val();

                        jQuery( 'h3#repair_update' ).text( 'Category Pages Updated:' + current_page );

                        jQuery( 'div#woowps_entry' ).html(data); // show response from the php script.

                        jQuery( '<div id="go"></div>' ).appendTo('div#woowps_entry');

                    },

                        error: function( data ) {

                        alert( 'lose' );

                         var current_page = jQuery('input.woowps_next_page').val();

                        jQuery( 'h3#repair_update' ).text( 'Category Pages Updated: ' + current_page );

                        jQuery( '<div id="go"></div>' ).insertAfter('div#woowps_entry');

                        jQuery('h3.timer').text( '0' );

                    }

                });

            });

        }

    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Try moving the `.submit` function into the `document.ready` function. Maybe `'form#woowps_next_page'` can't be found at the time your script is executed, because it isn't loaded yet.

Comment: Why are you binding the submit handler inside the `setInterval` callback? If `check` is truthy that will bind more and more handlers to that element, which doesn't seem right. But if `check` is falsey it won't bind a submit handler at all...

Comment: The timer is so I know when the form is stuck. It has to run ~17,000 times to get all the info from the API. But I use the timer to also trigger the check for the "check system". If the check is there, it's supposed to submit.

Comment: You should use something else to disable/enable the form once its ready an poll for that... not combine it with the event binding.

Comment: I originally had it as two separate functions. Made it one.

Answer (score 1):

The `submit(...)` function binds a handler to the submit event of a form. Meaning that the function you give it doesn't run at the time you call `submit(...)`, it will run, when the form is submitted. So bind the function once the document is loaded, but there is no need to bind it every second.

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

To prevent multiple requests from being send you could do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var requestSend = false;

    jQuery('form#woowps_next_page').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if(!requestSend) {
            requestSend = true;

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '...',
                data: jQuery("form#woowps_next_page").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    requestSend = false;
                    // whatever
                },
                error: function( data ) {
                    requestSend = false;
                    // error handling
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I'm having a problem with the return. Which is good because I've solved the issue! I didn't know you don't have to `.submit()` data to `POST` it through AJAX. I kept my timer function, because it let's me know when pages get stuck. Here's my answer:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function() {

        var check = jQuery('div#go').length;

        var count = parseInt(jQuery('h3.timer').html());

        count++;

        jQuery('h3.timer').text( count );

        if ( check === 1) {

            jQuery('div#go').remove();

            jQuery.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: '/wp-content/plugins/wps-woo/inc/category_repair_ajax.php',
                data: jQuery("form#woowps_next_page").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {



                    var current_page = jQuery('input.woowps_next_page').val();

                    jQuery( 'h3#repair_update' ).text( 'Category Pages Updated:' + current_page );

                    jQuery( 'div#woowps_entry' ).html(data); // show response from the php script.

                    jQuery( '<div id="go"></div>' ).appendTo('div#woowps_entry');

                    alert(current_page);

                 },

                 error: function( data ) {

                     alert('lose');

                     var current_page = jQuery('input.woowps_next_page').val();

                    jQuery( 'h3#repair_update' ).text( 'Category Pages Updated: ' + current_page );

                    jQuery( '<div id="go"></div>' ).insertAfter('div#woowps_entry');

                    jQuery('h3.timer').text( '0' );

                 }
          });

        }

    }, 1000);

});
```